# P5.js send request to Azure Custom Vision

Tags: javascript, azure, computer-vision, p5.js

So,

I take an image from a canvas using p5js and i want to send it to the Azure Custom Vision Service(the code bellow).

Is p5 image even the same as the normal js image(like when you take a capture from a video) ?

My problem is when i send a form as a json like :

```
let c = get(0,0,250,250);
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', prediction_URL, true);
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        console.log(http.responseText);
    }
} 
var objurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([c]));
http.send({
 url: prediction_URL,
 encoding: null,
 json: false,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'Prediction-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
},
body: objurl
});
```

But it gaves me "401 Acces Denied".

Is it even possible to send an image created using p5 via http request?

Comment: Is new Blob([c]) correct? why not new Blob(c) ? c will be an array of pixels from get correct?

Comment: if i use Blob(c) it gives me an error : "Failed to construct 'Blob': Iterator getter is not callable."
I don't master p5 but i think .get() returns an object with .pixels prop.
Still if i use new Blob(c.pixels); still going to give me acces denied.

Comment: I would start breaking the code down until you can figure out what is going on. Log out c and  c.pixels Does the pixels array contain what you would expect it to. If it does log out new Blob(c.pixels) and so on until you can narrow down where you are going wrong.

Comment: The thing is that i don’t know what should be the “format”

Comment: It says that the body should be binary data <Image type>  and I don’t know what that means.How can I transfer an image into binary ?

Comment: I think my answer should help you get your blob created from the object returned by get(). You may want to edit my answer to show how to incorporate it into your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p5.js get() method returns an object that has a canvas. Use this canvas object instead of the pixel array to create a blob object. The code below will create the blob you will just need to write the code to store it off and then put it into your call.

```
let c = get(0,0,250,250);
c.canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {// get content as blob
    console.log("callback blob: " + blob);
    // store the blob off so you can use it in your call
}, "image/jpeg", 0.75); // use the image type and quality parameter you need
```

See: [HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob)